# How does the game determine a successful defense?

Tags: age-of-empires-castle-siege

I was recently attacked and my keep was not destroyed, but the game said that my defense lost.

I thought that the keep had to be destroyed to fail a defense.

How many ways are there to lose a defense?

1. If the keep is destroyed?
2. If the attacker gets above 50%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much got it but I'll elaborate a little.

A successful offense is one in which the attacker gains at least 1 star. I'm not 100% sure of the specifics but my understanding is that you can gain 1 star for destroying the keep, 1 star for destroying 50% of the buildings (excluding the keep) and the final star for completely wiping out all buildings and towers (but not walls or decorations).